# How to add method to an Activity and have it called when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can someone help me to add:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button. */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

To this (the `MainActivity`):

```
package com.example.g;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
}
```

How do I combine these and get it to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add it below `onCreate`'s completion anywhere like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button 
    }
}
```

I have assumed that your button in xml contains `android:onClick="sendMessage"`.

Comment: May I please know the reason of a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {`enter code here`
   // Do something in response to button
}
}
```

#### On activity_main.xml use somthing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### On strings.xml add this line:

```
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

}